# I want to subtract one column from another in pandas, but I keep getting a copy error. Is there a better way to do this operation?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame TB_greater_2018 that 3 columns: country, e_inc_100k_2000 and e_inc_100k_2018. I would like to subtract e_inc_100k_2000 from e_inc_100k_2018 and then use those values returned to create a new column of the differences and then sort by the countries with the largest difference.  My current code is:

```
case_increase_per_100k = TB_greater_2018["e_inc_100k_2018"] - TB_greater_2018["e_inc_100k_2000"]
TB_greater_2018["case_increase_per_100k"] = case_increase_per_100k
TB_greater_2018.sort_values("case_increase_per_100k", ascending=[False]).head()
```

When I run this, I get a SettingwithCopyWarning.  Is there a way to do this without getting this warning?  Or just overall a better way of accomplishing the task?

Comment: Please reduce and enhance this into the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Your posted code fails for undefined symbols; images of critical text information are not acceptable.

Comment: the warning comes from your second code line, I see no benefit on splitting the first line from the second. If you still want to preserve your layout, then use `.iloc` or `.loc`, https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
TB_greater_2018["case_increase_per_100k"]  = TB_greater_2018["e_inc_100k_2018"] - TB_greater_2018["e_inc_100k_2000"]
TB_greater_2018.sort_values("case_increase_per_100k", ascending=[False]).head()
```

It looks like the error is from finding the difference and using that as a column in separate operations, although tbh I'm not clear why that would be.

Comment: I believe the answer to `I'm not clear why that would be` is because if intermediary operations are made between the creation of the new column and it's assignment the index and or shape of one or both of them could change and you can get funky results

Comment: I checked to determine what version of pandas I was using the _version_ attribute and it said 0.25.1.  I then attempted to update pandas using pip install --upgrade pandas.  It now says that I am using version 1.0.3.  Either way I am still getting the error.  I am working in juptyer notebook if that is of any relevance.  My apologies I am still very new to python.

Comment: no worries, that particular error has bedeviled me as well. Maybe try outside of jupyter, e.g. using ipython or the regular python interpreter (which can be invoked by calling `python` from the command line). In fact I dont get the error even when using your two-line version so this has nothing to do with splitting the operation, which at least makes sense.